Failed to start bolt.service - Thunderbolt system service
First of all let's say that I really don't have any experience with Linux and Ubuntu at all, so keep in mind. I was given a laptop today with Ubuntu 22.04 version (it was I think) and decided to update to the latest ( because it prompt me ) before using it. So the update process went almost smoothly with a few warning about moving some packages to snap and removing apps like Thunderbird to snap.
After the upgrade and the restart the laptop stays in a screen (terminal I think) which shows a few errors:
[FAILED] Failed to start dnsmasq.service - ...weight DHCP and caching DNS server.
[ OK ] Reached target nns-lookup.target - Host and Network lookups.
[ OK ] Started gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
[FAILED] Failed to start fwupd-refresh.service - Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.
[FAILED] Failed to start fwupd.service - Firmware update daemon.
[FAILED] Failed to start bolt.service - Thirderbolt system service.
[FAILED] Failed to start polkit.service - Authorization Manager
[FAILED] Failed to start bolt.service - Thirderbolt system service.
[FAILED] Failed to start polkit.service - Authorization Manager
[FAILED] Failed to start nmbd.service - Samba NMB Daemon.
[FAILED] Failed to start bolt.service - Thirderbolt system service.

And that's all. Nothing happens. The new version of the Ubuntu was 24.04
